# Read and compare images in folder using Perl

Tags: perl, scripting

I am trying to read and compare large number of image files in a folder. But I am not able to read the image file.

Code snippet :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Image::Compare;

opendir my $ref_dir, "./" or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @ref_files = readdir $ref_dir;
closedir $ref_dir;

print $#ref_files;

my($cmp) = Image::Compare->new();


$cmp->set_image1(
        img  => './'.$ref_files[0],  #one instance - reading first file in the folder
        type => 'bmp',
    );
```

The code is throwing the following error - "Unable to read image data from file './.': 'Could not open ./.: Permission denied' at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Image/Compare.pm line 162. "

The code works fine if I provide the file name directly - img  => './image.bmp'. So it can't be a permission issue.

Comment: Check the **permission** of `$ref_files[0]` file.

Comment: it works when I give the file name as a string directly. So it is not a permission issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message seems pretty clear.

> Unable to read image data from file './.': 'Could not open ./.: Permission denied

The first file you're getting back from `opendir()` is the current directory (`.`) - and it's no surprise that Image::Compare can't get the image data that it wants from that file!

Perhaps you should add a filter to only return the files you're interested in.

```
my @ref_files = grep { -f } readdir $ref_dir;
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue is fixed now